# Disable auto correction of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

When I try to edit texts in my iPhone application (`UITextfield`), it auto-corrects my input.

Could you let me know how can I disable this?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
UITextField* f = [[UITextField alloc] init];
f.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

Comment: Also if yo want **autocapitalization** off: `f.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;`

Comment: Hello @Caffeine, How we can enable the same option for NSTextfield (Mac app)?

Answer (score 35):

### Swift version

I landed here looking for a Swift version of this:

```
myInput.autocorrectionType = .No
```

Also read the answer by [@MaikelS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239975/1664443)

**Swift 3.0**

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .no
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `UITextInputTraits` protocol to achieve this:

```
myInput.autoCorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/autocorrectionType) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

The Interface Builder also has a dropdown field to disable this. As you're more likely to create textfields in the interface builder, look for it there. You can find it in the Attributes Inspector next to 'Correction'.

Answer (score 7):

you can also set this in the storyboard by choosing the 'attributes inspector' and under 'correction' you can choose: 'Default', 'yes' and 'no'
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (void)disableAutoCorrectionsForTextfieldsAndTextViewGlobally {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    struct objc_method_description autocorrectionTypeMethodDescription =
        protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(UITextInputTraits),
                                      @selector(autocorrectionType), NO, YES);
    IMP noAutocorrectionTypeIMP_TEXT_FIELD =
        imp_implementationWithBlock(^(UITextField *_self) {
          return UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        });
    IMP noAutocorrectionTypeIMP_TEXT_VIEW =
        imp_implementationWithBlock(^(UITextView *_self) {
          return UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        });
    class_replaceMethod([UITextField class], @selector(autocorrectionType),
                        noAutocorrectionTypeIMP_TEXT_FIELD,
                        autocorrectionTypeMethodDescription.types);
    class_replaceMethod([UITextView class], @selector(autocorrectionType),
                        noAutocorrectionTypeIMP_TEXT_VIEW,
                        autocorrectionTypeMethodDescription.types);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, you can use the `.disableAutocorrection(true)` modifier.

Hiere is a real life example:

```
VStack {
    TextField("title", text: $LoginModel.email)
        .autocapitalization(.none)
        .disableAutocorrection(true)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

This is how I am achieving for email address field in my project

```
private let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Email address")
    tf.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    tf.autocorrectionType = .no        //disable auto correction
    tf.autocapitalizationType = .none   //disable default capitalization
    return tf
}()
```

CustomTextField is my extension class (not important here)