# UITextField - cancel suggested correction not working

Tags: uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` defined programatically. When I write something, I get a suggested correction. If I tap the "X" for not accepting the correction, the correction is still made. Any suggestions to solve this issue? I'm defining it like this:

```
CGRect frame =CGRectMake(10 ,0 , 290, 44);
self.textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
self.textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
self.textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
[self.textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
self.textField.secureTextEntry = NO;
self.textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
self.textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
self.textField.delegate = self;
[self.textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeySearch];
```

Comment: did you check this [Disable auto correction of iPhone text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827310/disable-auto-correction-of-iphone-text-field) Adriana?

Comment: If I do that, I don't get a suggestion for correcting the text. I want the suggestion, but I also want to either accept it or now.