# Disable autocorrection for UITextField in whole application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I want to disable Autocorrection on all textfields in my application. I'm aware of the `autocorrectionType` property on UITextField. However, I didn't subclass UITextField when I started to develop my application. So I'm looking for a solution to disable autocorrect on all my TextField with a single line of code.

I tried using `[UITextField appearance]`, which works for the keyboard appearance:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

But not for autocorrection, since the following line of code:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
```

Results in a inconsistency exception:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on UIKit if you see this assertion.'
```

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe that has more to do with the textFieldDelegate class than the textField itself. Did you add that class?

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Not sure what you mean by adding the `textFieldDelegate`. I'm starting to think the autocorrection properties are not implemented in `UITextField`'s appearance proxy, which is a shame :/. Perhaps I should actually 'file a radar on UIKit' as it says in the exception message.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/autocorrectionType check that out as well as these links: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474824/iphone-issue-disabling-auto-cap-autocorrect-on-a-uitextfield and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827310/disable-auto-correction-of-iphone-text-field

Comment: Let me know if the Apple Developer link helps. `UITextInputTraits` and this method apparently controls that. `optional var autocorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionType { get set }` maybe that works?

Comment: @lukesIvi Yeah well, I know how to disable Autocorrection on a single field, that's not the issue here. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I did, i'm just looking for different methods that you can dd into the app delegate that could override the textField auto-correct. Sorry... Would be very curious to find out the answer though! Good luck.

Comment: have you find the answer @Hless

Comment: @AsimRazaKhan, nope. I guess it's just not possible

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go with sub-classing **UITextField**:

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField
@end
@implementation CustomTextField
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

        // same way add all the generalize properties which you require for all the textfields. 
    }
return self;
}
```

Now use **CustomTextField** in all over your project (either in code or in storyboard).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about subclassing, I was actually wondering why the oneliner won't work (as it does with keyboard appearance). Subclassing is definitely not a one-line solution since I'll need to replace all UITextField occurrences.

Comment: This might be because `AutocorrectionType` property not been considered as a part of `UIAppearance` (simply not a UI, it comes under User Experience). Whereas `UIKeyboardAppearance` is `UI Appearance` related (visible on UI).